# C language - Too Few Arguments

Tags: c

I've looked over many questions regarding the same topic but I still cant to seem to find my problem. I get the error "too few function arguments".

I did not attach my full code but I attached where the problem is.

The problem indicates to be here.

```
if (EWPED_SW == 1)
{
    PED_Control();
}
```

Here is the function that I am calling.

```
void PED_Control(char Direction, char Num_Sec)
{
Display_Lower_Digit(0x00);
Display_Upper_Digit(0x00);
for (char i = Num_Sec-1; i>0 ; i--)
{
    if (Direction == 0)
    {
      Display_Upper_Digit(i);  
    }
    else
    {
      Display_Lower_Digit(i);   
    }
    Wait_One_Second_With_Buzzer();
    }
    Display_Upper_Digit(0x00);
    Display_Lower_Digit(0x00);
    Wait_One_Second_With_Buzzer(); 
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well yeah - `PED_Control` is defined to take two arguments, and you've called it with none.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have tried " PED_Control(char,char); " but I still get errors

Comment: `char` is a type, not a value.  You have to decide what you want the `Direction` and `Num_Sec` to be.  It's not clear what they are supposed to do exactly, but if you want the direction to be 1 and the number of seconds to be 13, you do `PED_Control(1, 13);`.  You can also use variables or any other expressions.  Just like all the function calls within `PED_Control` are doing.

Comment: @NateEldredge ah I see, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating the function `void PED_Control(char Direction, char Num_Sec)` you're expecting some arguments in this function.

But in the function call, you're not passing any arguments

```
if (EWPED_SW == 1)
{
    PED_Control();
}
```

You should provide 2 character arguments while making the function call like below.

`PED_Control(arg1,arg2);`

2nd you need to change to function definition to int arguments
`PED_Control(char Direction, char Num_Sec)` to `PED_Control(int Direction, int Num_Sec)`